# "Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 has stopped working", at startup

Tags: visual-studio-2013

[image]

Unable to start visual studio, even not getting any error code are specific reason. Is this issues causes because of Microsoft visual studio licensing protocol.

Comment: There's no way of determining the problem from this alone - try checking Event Viewer and seeing if there's any further information in there. Is this a new install of Visual Studio or was it previously working? If you can't see anything in the event logs it's probably worth uninstalling and reinstalling it.

Comment: yes, I got to know the issue caused for such, here our system admin disabled the microsoft service and due to that it wan not starting up and even it was not showing any information related to issue.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are facing this issue with **Visual Studio 2013 community edition** on windows 8.1:

We had same issue on 3 PCs today and we found the solution below

- Unplug the network cable
- Open Visual Studio (It should open now)
- Sign out from your existing login in Visual Studio
- Plug the network cable
- Open Visual Studio (It should open now)
- Sign In and it should work now

Found such details on below link
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/38936de0-aad0-413a-8181-0eab27c189ba/microsoft-visual-studio-2013-has-stopped-working?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel -> Program Features and on the left, you can see "**Turn Windows features on or off**". In the following dialog box, *uncheck* **.NET Framework 3.5** and click OK. It will require a restart. *(If it is already unchecked, check it!)*

Try starting VS2013 then. It will work fine. It worked for me :)